# Boto3 not directing to the endpoint_url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, url, boto3

I'm currently trying to connect to my enterprise s3 URL (which is not amazon web-service) using boto3 and I have the following error.

EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://s3.fr-par.amazonaws.com/my_buket...." which is absolutely not the enpoint given in the code.

```
s3 = boto3.resource(service_name='s3',
                    aws_access_key_id= 'XXXXXX',
                    aws_secret_access_key='YYYYYYY',
                    endpoint_url= 'https://my_buket.s3.my_region.my_company_enpoint_url')

my_bucket=s3.Bucket(s3_bucket_name)
bucket_list = []
for file in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='boston.csv'):
    bucket_list.append(file.key)
```

As can be seen in the [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn4Zm.png) boto3 tries to connect to a amazonaws url, which is not that of my enterprise. Finally I want to indicate that I am able to connect to my enterprise s3 using minIO https://docs.min.io/ which indicate there no errors in the aws_access_key_id, the aws_secret_access_key and endpoint_url I use with boto3.

I have executed the code using a python 3.9 environment (Boto3 version 1.22.1) a anaconda 3.9 environment (Boto3 version 1.22.0) and a jupyter notebook always with same error. The OS is an Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS virtualized on Oracle VM virtual box.

Comment: This basic code works for me.  Have you tried using an up to date version of boto3 with python3?

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue with the amazonaws url being used, instead of the custom one specified in endpoint_url... did you manage to get it to work ?

Comment: Hi @JulienV, yes I have manage, I will post the answer

Comment: Thanks @LucasM.Uriarte, i managed to solve it too... In fact, my problem was that i had the region typed wrong, and it turns out that it's the retry mechanism in boto3 that was changing the url in the second try (seems like a bug ;)), but otherwise the initial url was the right one, so just fixing the region in my case fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some people seem to have the same problem, I'm posting the solution I found.

For some reason the code in the question still doesn't work for me. Alternatively, I handle pointing to my enterprise's S3 just by first creating a session and creating the resource and client from it. Note that in endpoint_url, no bucket is indicated.

Since there is no bucket in endpoint_url, you have access to all buckets associated with the credential pass, and therefore it is necessary to specify the bucket in the resource and client instances methods.

```py
session = boto3.Session(region_name=my_region)

resource = session.resource('s3', 
                 endpoint_url='https://s3.my_region.my_company_enpoint_url',
                 aws_access_key_id='XXXXXX',
                 aws_secret_access_key='YYYYYY')

client = session.client('s3', 
                 endpoint_url='https://s3.my_region.my_company_enpoint_url',
                 aws_access_key_id='XXXXXX',
                 aws_secret_access_key='YYYYYY')

client.upload_file(path_to_local_file, bucket_name, upload_path, 
                   Callback=call, 
                   ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs)
```

Answer (score 0):

`https://my_buket.s3.my_region.my_company_enpoint_url` is not the endpoint. The list of valid S3 endpoints is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_region). But normally you don't have to specify it explicitly. Boto3 will "know" which endpoint to use for each region.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but those endpoints are only for amazon web service, my s3 URL is not from amazon. As mentioned in the question my endpoint is perfectly correct, I have test it with MinIO, which perfectly allows me to connect

Comment: Cloudian Hyperstore is an example of a storage solution with an S3 interface that is locally hosted rather than hosted by AWS.  As per OP question, it is necessary to specify the endpoint, and legitimate to utilise a Virtual-hosted–style format to create a direct URL formed by concatenating the bucket name and host URL.